# Why the object doesn't switch sides when collides from one side unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm trying to change the direction of the enemy when collides with a wall or the character. However, it doesn't work for the wall that the enemy bumps into, but only stays where it is.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

In this picture, the goomba switches the direction when bumps into Mario, however the same does not happen when the wall is hit.

What happens instead is this:

[image]

The Goomba stands still.

Here's the code of the goomba:

```
public class GoombaController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f;
    private Vector2 force = Vector2.left;
    
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(force * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if ((this.transform.position.x - coll.collider.transform.position.x) < 0) {
            force = Vector2.left;
        } else if ((this.transform.position.x - coll.collider.transform.position.x) > 0) {
            force = Vector2.right;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I use a tile map to generate the level, and the ground and the walls are on the same tile map.

If anything else is needed as info, just leave a comment below the question.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your `coll`? Are you sure the `OnCollisionEnter2D` is not being called by the ground under the goomba?

Comment: Well if it was triggered by the ground, then the goomba would switch direction all the time; resulting in it standing still.

Comment: No it wouldn't, OnCollisonEnter only runs once, the first time it hits the collision, if you had put it on OnCollisionStay, then it would change directions all the time, so it probably is the ground that's triggering it, seeing as you define force to be left at the start and in your image he's walking right, it most likely gets triggered right from the start.

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work. Also, since I don't use OnCollisionStay, my code does not execute when the collision is continuing. It only runs the initial time which switches the direction. So I think the problem is not at OnCollisionStay.